# Done button does not appear on Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am defining the EditText as below. I want the `Done` button to appear in the soft keyboard but I am getting `Return` button instead.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCommentContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_gradient"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:hint="@string/strHintContentComment"
        android:maxLines ="4"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add `inputType` too and then check again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try?

```
 editText.setImeOptions(editText.getImeOptions()| EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

With

```
  android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: I added it and it works but I lost the text wrap functionality. What I need is the text to wrap to next line instead of scrolling along with `Done` button

Comment: However, if you have android:inputType=textMultiline you're going to write an extra line of code:
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

Answer (score 3):

You need to add:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

done button will show, but you can not use **done button** and **return button(next line)** same time on softkeyboard